# How can i keep some of the checkboxes prechecked in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I am using GWT and I want to have some of the checkboxes prechecked.How to achieve this?

My code is here :

```
if (myValue1.equalsIgnoreCase("First"))
 {
 panel1.clear();
 for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
  {
   checkBox1 = new CheckBox("Item" + i);
   panel1.add(checkBox1);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be how you check a box

checkBox1.setValue(true);